# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

Upgraded my Rails 4.2.5 app to 5 and now I get this error when doing bundle install:

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  activejob (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
    globalid (>= 0.3.6) was resolved to 0.3.7, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)

google-webfonts-rails (~> 0.0.4) was resolved to 0.0.4, which depends on
  activesupport (< 5.0, > 3.2.0)

jbuilder (~> 2.5) was resolved to 2.6.0, which depends on
  activesupport (< 5.1, >= 3.0.0)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.0)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.0)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.0)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.0)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.0)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.0)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.0)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
    rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
      activesupport (< 6.0, >= 4.2.0)

spring was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
  activesupport (>= 4.2)

rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
    activesupport (>= 4.0)
```

Fairly new to rails and never ran into to this problem before. I tried gem update and bundle update, but still get this error. 
Thank you.

Comment: `rails 5` requires `activesupport > 5`. please refer this doc to upgrade your `rails 4` application to `rails 5` https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/how-to-upgrade-to-rails-5

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is explained here:

`google-webfonts-rails (~> 0.0.4) was resolved to 0.0.4, which depends on
  activesupport (< 5.0, > 3.2.0)`

You need to use a more recent version of the `google-webfonts-rails` gem, once that supports rails 5, or you need to get rid of that gem entirely.